# IllegalArgumentException error

Tags: java, model-view-controller, illegalargumentexception

So I am attempting to use MVC(model, view, controller) to format my code and when attempting to add the view to the actual application I get an error that says that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl
    at java.awt.Container.add"
While I know what the error is I have no idea what I should do(not use MVC or find some sort of work-around) and would appreciate any help. Below I will have the code of the two classes.

Here is where the application is run from:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class FencingApplication here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        InputView view = new InputView();
        InputModel model = new InputModel();
        InputController ctrl = new InputController(view, model);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("");
        window.setSize(500, 600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = new Container();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add( view, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        JButton btList = new JButton( "List" );
        JButton btPools = new JButton("Pools");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        buttonPanel.add(btList);
        buttonPanel.add(btPools);
        c.add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        btList.addActionListener( ctrl );//where is the action performed method defined
        btPools.addActionListener( ctrl );
        window.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

And here is the view class:

```
import javax.swing.*; //Jframe/JButton/JLabel/etc
import java.awt.*; //container
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class InputView here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class InputView extends JFrame implements Observer
{
    JLabel lbPaste = new JLabel("Please paste the seeding here.");
    JTextArea taPaste = new JTextArea();
    JButton btPools = new JButton("Pools");

    JLabel lbNum = new JLabel("Please input the number of pools you want to have.");
    JTextField tfNum = new JTextField();
    public InputView()
    {   
        JPanel numPanel = new JPanel();
        numPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        numPanel.add(lbNum, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        numPanel.add(tfNum, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel pastePanel = new JPanel();
        pastePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pastePanel.add(lbPaste, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pastePanel.add(new JScrollPane(taPaste), BorderLayout.CENTER);



        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        c.add(numPanel);
        c.add(pastePanel);

        setTitle( "Pools" );
        setSize( 350, 500 );//width then height
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }
    public void update( Observable obs, Object obj )
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Container` is the superclass of e.g. `Panel`, `JPanel`, `Window`, `JFrame`, etc.

`JFrame` is a window, so you shouldn't (and in fact can't, as you found out here) add it to another component. `JFrame` is a [top-level container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Actually, it's probably the case that you shouldn't be using `new Container()` directly at all. For example, if you want a panel, you should use `JPanel`. It's kind of hard for me to tell exactly what you intended, since adding a `JFrame` to another component is an error. I see you adding stuff to `c` but I don't see you doing anything else with it.

So:

- `JFrame` is a window.
- `JFrame` has a content pane, which is the panel inside the window. (The default content pane is actually a `JPanel`, even though `getContentPane()` returns it as a `Container`.)
- If you want to put stuff in a `JFrame`, you add the stuff to the content pane.
- You don't need to add a `JFrame` to anything, just create it with `new` and call `setVisible(true)`.

Those are the basics of how to use a `JFrame` correctly.

I also highly recommend the [Swing tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) if you haven't read them. They are really pretty good.